# node 6.11.3 NODE_EXE not found in IntelliJ

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, npm, environment-variables

I've updated my project to use node 6.11.3. When I now try to start a npm-script by using the Run-configurations provided from IntelliJ, I always receive the following error:

> Error: Failed to replace env in config: ${NODE_EXE}

**Important:** This error appears only if I start npm from within my project. If I use the windows cmd, the error doesn't appear.

What could possibly have changed between node 6.11.2 and 6.11.3? Because with the prior version, everything worked fine.

A workaround for me is to add the NODE_EXE variable to my run configuration, but In my opinion, that shouldn't be needed, because it worked in 6.11.2 too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks as if you have `${NODE_EXE}` variable set in one of your `npmrc` files (see https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc#files), and it can't be properly expanded for some reason when you run your script in the IDE.

- is the issue specific to certain project?
- how many npm versions do you have installed? Please check that npm chosen in [Node.js Interpreters](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.3/node-js-interpreters-dialog.html) dialog is the same as you use in cmd shell?
- please create an `env.js` file with `console.log(process.env)` and try running it via npm (`"env" : "node env.js"`) in both cmd console and WebStorm - what is the result?